# Go command to get list of keywords or reserved words?

Tags: go

In python they have provided command to list the keywords in it by

```
>>> import keyword
>>> print(keyword.kwlist)
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'async', 'await', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

is there a similar way in go?

Comment: You can use this link instead: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords

Comment: That "command" in Python is just Python code, with Python operating as a REPL. Go is not a scripting language and does not have a REPL, and listing keywords at runtime in a compiled binary has zero value, so that is not part of the stdlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `token` package has a function `IsKeyword`. The code checks the existence of the string  in

```
var keywords map[string]Token
```

This var is not exported, unfortunately. But you can build the same map like it is done in the standard lib:

```
func init() {
    keywords = make(map[string]Token)
    for i := keyword_beg + 1; i < keyword_end; i++ {
        keywords[tokens[i]] = i
    }
}
```

`keyword_beg` and `keyword_end` are constant values that mark beginning and end of the keyword constants. These also are not exported, but you can still use the value (resolved to 60 and 86).

So you convert int values from 60 to 86 to `token.Token` and then call `Token.String`. Like this

```
tokens := make([]token.Token, 0)
for i := 61; i < 86; i++ {
    tokens = append(tokens, token.Token(i))
}
fmt.Println(tokens)
```